# Install4j - how to change default font size associated with alert messages

Tags: install4j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dv11.png)I am looking for an option to change Font size and color associated with default alert messages displayed with  Util.showMessage(message) and Util.showErrorMessage(message)

we have noticed that alert message font size and color are changed with latest (7.x) install4j version.

[Alert message with 7.x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbqvR.png)

Comment: Did you get my reply to the email you sent to support@ej-technologies.com?

Comment: No. i have not yet received.

Comment: Probably went to the spam folder, I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In install4j 7.x you can get old-style alerts like in install4j 6.x and earlier by selecting the installer in the Installer->Screens & Actions step and adding

```
-Dinstall4j.noNativeDialogs=true
```

to the "VM parameters" property.